# My unity game fails to open in my mobile

Tags: unity, android, crash

I'm new to Unity, and want to make a android game. I made a very simple scene:

- A sphere
- A cube (floor)
- A simple script that moves the sphere by touch.

I tried it with unity remote and it works fine. But the problem manifests when I build it to test it. When I run it on my mobile, it opens and suddenly gets closed. I don't know what is the actual problem. what should i do?

Comment: Did you try using [Android adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) to see what error pops up? Can you guide is with the process of what steps you followed to compile it?